# Minify C3 code in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, minify, bundling-and-minification

I want to minify C# codes(files) inside Visual Studio 2017. Is there any extension or other ways to do this. I've searched already and nothing useful was found. I know that there are ways to minify js, CSS or HTML files, but I need minifier for C# if there exist

Comment: https://github.com/KvanTTT/CSharp-Minifier

Comment: apart from that this is only asking for a tool, why would anybody need this? C# Code will be compiled, minify it will only make it hard to maintain... 

Comment: Thanks, @Smartis. Except for compilation, I need to rewrite local variables and simplify them. Because compile the code, will change it completely, it could not help me, and it has its own usages.

Comment: @Smartis one usage would be where you're hosting c# scripts inside an app/game that then dynamically compiles them. An example I know of is the game "Space Engineers" by Keen Software. They allow you to write "ingame scripts" using C#, but you are limited by a fixed character count - this is because the multiplayer game needs to transfer any scripts over the network to other players, and as such, keeping that data size down is a good idea... so minification of your C# script means more actual code for the same amount of used characters, or less network traffic for the same code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class that inherits from the base class [CSharpSyntaxRewriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxrewriter?view=roslyn-dotnet) and use it to minify the code based on however it is you wish to minify it.

A starter would be removing all syntax trivia, which can be easily achieved with the following implementation of the `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` base class:

```
public class TriviaRemover : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode Visit(SyntaxNode node) => base.Visit(node).WithoutTrivia();

    public override SyntaxTrivia VisitTrivia(SyntaxTrivia trivia) => default;
}
```

To actually use this, something like the following example would work:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
  public class Foo
  {
      //Here some trivia to be removed
      public string bar = ""bar"";
  }");
var Mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var root = model.SyntaxTree.GetRoot();

var tr = new TriviaRemover();
var newRoot = tr.Visit(root);

Console.WriteLine(newRoot.GetText());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Have a look here for another example (where the example code above originated):
https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/using-a-csharp-syntax-rewriter/